# Solution of an algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $k>0$ and $\frac 1 2 \le a \le \frac 3 5$ be constants. Find all solutions $0<x<1$ (closed form) of the equation
$$
\frac k {a+x}=\left(\frac 1 x  -1\right)^{\frac 1{1-a}}
$$

Comment: It seems impossible to find a solution (closed form) even for some rational $a$.

Comment: I asked Wolfram|Alpha for a solution at $a=\frac12$. The answer it gave me was closed-form, but it looked completely insane. (I.e., far too wide to fit the whole solution on one line of text.)